# Why was the question about a mortgage formula off-topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, closed-questions

This question was asked recently and closed as off-topic:

[What is the formula for calculating the mortgage constant when payments are made at the beginning of the period?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/90702/10997)

The close reason given was "Questions about accounting are off-topic unless they relate directly to personal finance or investing from an individual's perspective."

Mortgages are a personal finance topic that we cover here very often, so I’m confused about this closure. Why was this particular question closed?

Comment: FWIW I think it's on-topic so have reopened (along with two others who had already voted that way). Hopefully the close voters will post their own rationale - we can always re-close it if they were right after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I just commented on the question, basic mortgage calculations are perfectly within the personal finance area of accounting.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Ganesh. The mods did not vote to close, and it seems it would have been re-opened via voting as well. If those who voted to close do not return to the question itself, they are not very likely to read this meta question.

I can't read minds, I can't really tell why they think it's off topic. It's a bit tedious, but it's the math behind mortgages, and clearly part of PF.